# Catching error from assert in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

Hi I am trying to catch error in a promise chain like:

```
it("Exception is thrown for Invalid Candidate",function(){
      return Election.deployed().then(function(instance){
           electionInstance = instance;
           candidateId = 99;
           return electionInstance.vote(candidateId,{from:accounts[1]});
      }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
           assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') => 0,"error message must contain revert");
           return electionInstance.candidates(1);
      }).then(function(candidate1){
           var voteCount = candidate1[0];
           assert.equal(voteCount,1,"candidate1 did not recieve any votes");
           return electionInstance.candidates(2);
      }).then(function(candidate2){
           var voteCount = candidate2[0];
           assert.equal(voteCount,0,"Candidate2 didnot recieve any votes");
      });
 });
```

but i get a syntax error near the error.message.
Cant find anything useful in the chaijs docs.
Is my approach wrong? How should i do this?
The error is as follows

```
/home/chance/Ethereum_Work/VotingApplication/test/election.js:48
           assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') => 0,"error message must contain revert");
                       ^


SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
at Mocha.run (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:514:10)
at /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-core/lib/test.js:125:1
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Comment: *"but i get a syntax error near the error.message"* really? maybe it's because the syntax is indeed invalid.

Comment: Post the error message.  If the error doesn't have the property `message` on it, it'll blow up trying to call `indexOf`

Comment: We'd happily help you understand the syntax error, but you'd have to share the exact contents of the syntax error with us, what line of code it occurs on and then we'd probably need to see what the variables involved in the syntax error contain.

Comment: What does `someAction()` reject?  I'm assuming some object that has a message property?  What does your syntax error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
error.message.indexOf('revert') => 0
```

is an invalid Javascript expression because the `=>` is used to denote a declaration of a fat arrow callback and this is not a proper location to put a callback so that is causing an error.

Did you perhaps mean this?

```
error.message.indexOf('revert') === 0
```

or this:

```
error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0
```

Comment: I'd guess he meant `>=`.

Comment: @Bergi - Good guess.  I added that as a possibility.

Comment: Yup sleepy coding is poison. >= it is Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So what would happen if instead of message, you put the below?

```
error.toString().indexOf('revert') >= 0
```

This successfully passes the test with the correct output.

Here is the source:

https://expertcodeblog.wordpress.com/2018/01/15/typescript-how-to-resolve-error-indexof-is-not-a-function/

Posted by MARCO BARBERO on 15 JANUARY 2018

Sometimes on TypeScript, when you call the indexOf() method you can get the error ‘indexOf is not a function‘. This happens when the data contained in the variable is represented by a number without other characters, even when the variable has been declared as a string.

To resolve the error you should use the toString() method:

```
myStringVar.toString().indexOf('mysubstring');
```